# MariaDB - Emulate MySQL 5.7 version number?

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb

I have been running MariaDB 5.5 on a linux server for several years.
Yesterday, I upgraded to MariaDB 10.11.3.

Now, my backup software has stopped backing up the databases, reporting an error that "MySQL 10.11 is not supported".

Since the backup software supports MySQL, it is likely expecting to receive version 5.7 from the server, and is being confused by receiving version 10.11.3.

**Is there any way to make MariaDB report version 5.7**, to make the backup software think we're running MySQL 5.7?  Since MariaDB 10.11 and MySQL 5.7 [are basically compatible](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compatibility-differences-incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between/) (if using the same storage engines) it shouldn't present a problem to back up, but reporting 5.7 will persuade the backup software to continue running.

Comment: What backup software?  Let's see the actual error messages in context.

Comment: @RickJames The backup software is N-Able Cove Data Protection (https://www.n-able.com/products/cove-data-protection) There is no context to the error message: it's the only error message.  The exact error message is: "Unsupported version of MySQL server: 10.11.3.0"  When the app attempted to run the last backup after the upgrade, this happened.  Their support states that "mariadb is not supported".

Answer (score 6):

Quote from [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/version/#changing-the-version-string):

> Some old legacy code may break because they are parsing the VERSION string and expecting a MySQL string or a simple version string like Joomla til API17, see MDEV-7780.
>
> From MariaDB 10.2, one can fool these applications by setting the version string from the command line or the my.cnf files with `--version=...`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I will try this next time the database can be restarted to apply the change.  Thanks!